# How to calculate molecular weight in python

Tags: python-3.x

The user will input the chemical formula. For example `CO2OHC5H18COO`, or something like that. Then, the output would be the molecular weight given that `C = 12.01`, `H = 1.008`, `O = 16`. I have this so far:

```
while(True):

    chemical_formula = input("Enter chemical formula, or enter to quit: ")

    length = len(chemical_formula)
    if chemical_formula == "":
        break
    else:
        char = list(chemical_formula)
        length = len(char)
        for i in char:
            if i == "C":
                c = 12.0107
            elif i == "H":
                h = 1.00794
            elif i == "O":
                o = 15.9994
            else:
                if char[i-1] == "C":
                    print(float(i)*c)
                elif char[i-1] == "H":
                    print(float(i)*h)
                elif char[i-1] == "O":
                    print(float(i)*o)
```

But I don't get why I can't use `(i-1)` to get the previous element in the for loop so I can multiply it to the number. Is there any other way to get the previous element of the string? Or maybe is there a different way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over index not over element, done as the example below:

```
chemical_formula = input("Enter chemical formula, or enter to quit: ")

length = len(chemical_formula)
if chemical_formula == "":
    break
else:
    char = list(chemical_formula)
    length = len(char)
    for i in range(length):
        if char[i] == "C":
            c = 12.0107
        elif char[i] == "H":
            h = 1.00794
        elif char[i] == "O":
            o = 15.9994
        else:
            if char[i-1] == "C":
                print(float(i)*c)
            elif char[i-1] == "H":
                print(float(i)*h)
            elif char[i-1] == "O":
                print(float(i)*o)
```